# Trying out my first BASH script, keep getting unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying to make a script that would pretty much automate this process:
http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/add-additional-ips-redhat

Wasn't too sure how well it would work, but didn't get too far before I could get the script to one. Below is the content of the script:

Editing with updated code:
Edit#2: Got it mostly working, however now it runs the loop and skips over the read propmt to get the static IP

```
   #!/bin/bash

path=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
echo "Let's get your IP added :)"
echo""


getnewip()
{
echo read -p "Enter the new IP Address you wish to add: " staticip
}

getserverinfo()
{
gateway=$(netstat -rn | sed -n 3p | awk '{print $2}')
netmask=$(ifconfig eth1 | grep -i 'netmask' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $4}')
clone=$( ifconfig | grep eth1 | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d: -f2 )
}


rangechecks()
{
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
ls ifcfg-eth1-range*

filename==$1
if [[ ! -f $filename ]]; then
touch "$filename"
echo "Created \"$filename\""

fi

digit=1
while true; do
temp_name=$filename-$digit
if [[ ! -f temp_name ]]; then
touch "$temp_name"
echo "Created $path\"$temp_name\""
digit=$((digit + 1 ))
fi
done
}


writeinterfacefile()
{
cat >> "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/$1" << EOF
IPADDR_START=$staticip
IPADDR_END=$staticip
NETMASK=$netmask
CLONENUM_START=$((clone+1))
EOF

echo ""
echo "Your information was saved in the file '$1'."
echo ""


}
{
clear
getserverinfo
echo ""
echo "Please verify this information: "
echo "Gateway Address: " "$gateway"
echo "Netmask: " "$netmask"
echo "Your new IP: " "$staticip"
echo ''

while true; do
read -p "Is this information correct? [y/N]" yn
case $yn in
[Yy]* ) $writeinterfacefile;;
[Nn]* ) print "$getserverinfo" && exit ;;
 * ) echo 'Please enter Y or n';;
esac
done
}
```

I'm fairly new at scripting, so excuse the horrid syntax. My eye is on that EOF but I have no clue.

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Actually found that, now all the errors are gone but still getting undesired results.

Comment: Try not to use `echo ""` or `echo` to insert a blank line in your output. Use `echo -e "\nWhatever..\n"` or `printf "\nWhatever..\n\n"` The `-e` option to `echo` enables interpretation of escapes. `printf` always interprets escapes.  Your scripting (finding unexpected EOFs, etc.) will benefit greatly if you use an editor with `syntax highlighting` and properly `indent` your code. On Linux `konsole/gedit` are gui-editors with solid highlighting, `vim/emacs` are great text based editors. On the Windows side, `notepad++` has good highlighting and is `GPL`.

Answer (score 1):

`rangechecks`has no `}`, your `while` has no `done`...
You should indent your code. I started doing that, and noticed the error right away.

Other things:

- Single quotes don't expand variables, `'/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts//$1` won't do what you want it to.
- `echo ""` is equivalent to `echo`.
- `foo='bar'; echo "blah" echo -n $foo` will output 'blah echo -n bar'.
- `exit` exits the script, I'm not sure that's what you think it does.
- `[y/N]` usually means `N` by default (the capital letter).
  Also, you then ask to `enter Y or n`. Be consistent!
- When using a variable as a parameter, double quote it. This ensures it stays the way it is (as one parameter, and not expanded by the shell).

Comment: Updated the code in the main post. As for the y/N part, I only needed to do that once?! The rest I think I fixed up. The empty echos are for spaces, dunno why I'm in that habit lol. Now I'm getting  addips.sh: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: Fixed it, my fi was after my done >.> Lmao. Script works now, thanks boss!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the closing curly brace of function `rangechecks`

Also, don't indent the shebang in the first line.

Comment: After adding one, I get the following: 
addips.sh: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
addips.sh: line 38: `}'